# Flashlight crashes systems Camera App

Tags: android, android-widget, camera, flashlight

I am making a Flashlight app, currently its widget.
I was wondering how would I emulate functionality of samsungs assistive light widget (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYR9jqo0vvc&feature=player_embedded#!)?

If I turn my light on, the camera app is not going to work, however with this widget, samsung made it somehow work. I have no idea at all, for all I know Camera.open() locks the camera to the process, so Camera app cannot access it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard Android camera API does not allow for setting the flash to torch mode, and then allowing some other application to use the camera. If the Flashlight app does not release the camera, then the standard camera app cannot work. If the Flashlight app does release the camera, then the flash will turn off.

Samsung must have extended the Android APIs with a custom feature to enable/disable the torch mode without requiring locking the camera. If they wish, they could document this additional capability, but presumably the added APIs only exist on the Galaxy S3 or other similar Samsung devices; it would not allow you to write code that works on all Android devices.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how about Camera.unlock() ? Isnt that what we are looking for possibly ?

Comment: Camera.unlock() is used to allow some other process use your camera instance - it was originally written to allow you to pass your Camera to a MediaRecorder, which needed to access your camera object from behind the scenes.  It won't help you let other apps use the camera while you have it open.